# If I set up a world border, does it apply to all dimensions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am tempted to set up a world border in Minecraft but I don't want to be limited in the Nether.

Does the world border effect all dimensions?

If it does can it be configured not to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[World borders](https://minecraft.wiki/w/World_border) do affect the nether. This is stated on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/World_border):

> In the Nether, the world border's dimensions are the same as the Overworld's.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to configure how world borders behave in different dimensions at this time.

World border in the nether:

[image]

I have not been able to test world borders in the end.

Comment: Considering how the nether scales movement compared to the Overworld, how does this affect the borders? Are they the same absolute size or is the border similarly scaled? If the former then could you not escape the world border by dimension hopping?

Comment: "The borders dimensions are the same as the overworlds"

Comment: Just curious, does it affect(effect?) The End too?

Comment: I am not sure, I will test this.

Comment: Yes, it applies in the end as well. The Ender Dragon can pass through it no problem though, just like any other block. Screenshot at http://imgur.com/HCeOfEF

Comment: @TomHart You had it right.  Use affect as a verb, and effect as a noun.  I always remember it with this sentence: "You can affect something and produce a noticeable effect."